# Problem retrieving data from Fastapi endpoint with Nextjs React frontend

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, next.js, fastapi

```
@router.get('/public',response_class=HTMLResponse)
def job_list_view(request:Request):
    async def get_todos() -> dict:
        todos = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "item": "Read a book."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "item": "Cycle around town."
        }
            ]
        return { "data": todos }
```

When I try to access that endpoint using Postman I get "Internal Server Error"

When I try to access that endpoint with a Nextjs app:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const jobs = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/public/')
  console.log(jobs)
  const res = jobs.json()
  return {
    props: { jobs: res },
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
    error - unhandledRejection: FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:8000/public/ reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    error - Error: Error serializing `.jobs` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
    Reason: `object` ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

And in my Fastapi backend console I get "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'" as follows:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63133 - "GET /public/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 366, in run_asgi       
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__       
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 269, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\authentication.py", line 48, in __call__    
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__      
    raise e
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__      
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 251, in app
    response = actual_response_class(response_data, **response_args)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\responses.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.body = self.render(content)
  File "D:\TEMP\job_search - SQL\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\responses.py", line 57, in render
    return content.encode(self.charset)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have searched through hundreds of posts and articles and still not able to resolve this. There is an example here :  https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-react/ but I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying your endpoint is going to be return an HTML response - i.e. a string (`str`):

```
@router.get('/public', response_class=HTMLResponse)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

.. but you're returning a dict, which is *not* an HTML response. Instead, just remove the `response_class`, since you're not validating your response against a schema or anything else in your current structure.

```py
@router.get('/public')
def job_list_view(request: Request):
    todos = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "item": "Read a book."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "item": "Cycle around town."
        }
    ]
    return {"data": todos}
```

This will return the data as JSON, which is what your JavaScript code attempts to read.

Comment: You are completely right! Problem solved :)